# Android memory leak with images from assets

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am getting image from assets and assigning to imageView, everything works fine but when I see heap memory size it keeps on growing when I load the same page again and again, Below is the code what I am using to get Image from assets folder.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

    return bitmap;
}

    //Code to assign bitmap to imageview
    ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    try {
        Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromAsset("full/" + Uri.parse(menuItem.getFullImage()).getLastPathSegment());
        itemImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is all what I am doing, is there any where I need to recycle the bitmap?

Comment: See here http://www.thiagorosa.com.br/en/how-to/minimize-outofmemory-errors.  I use it often, but without the call to the GC.  In my opinion, it does nothing useful and is often used in an attempt to hide sins ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am using a parent activity which is extended by all activities and that activity is registered with LocationListener, so LocationListener is preventing the activity from destroying.

Answer (score 2):

In your onDestroy add

```
   @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {

            super.onDestroy();
            if(bm != null)
            {
                bm.recycle();

            }
}
```

Additionally take memory dump and analyze the dump use [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) . In case you need help with that refer to this video [tutorial](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&ei=I-FdUOq5IMW3rAe13ICoDA&usg=AFQjCNEfUDM7yYu-Cb6hrLjEOm5xk29LkA&sig2=zVXzyxwz7xuSwrzT72jsPg)

Comment: Thanks . Even though ,Your answer doesn't work to me. But It solved my problem indrectly... I used an AssetFileDescriptor Object and didn't close ... So It was leaked too... I found the AssetFileDescriptor Object could be closed by close() method. In any case.I solved my problem.Anyways , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once check this

after you complete using the bitmap use the following statement bm = null; 
and write System.gc(); in the ondestroy() (and if needed in onPause()) and see if that works

Comment: Calling the GC is not a proper way to fix memory issues.

Comment: @Matsemann oh then sorry for the answer.
does using bm = null; solve the issue?

Comment: its ok but how did you use it?

Comment: public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (bm != null) {
            Log.i("recycle?", "yes");
            bm.recycle();
        }
    }

Comment: did you use  Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromAsset("full/" + Uri.parse(menuItem.getFullImage()).getLastPathSegment()); as it is? or did you change it to   bm = getBitmapFromAsset("full/" + Uri.parse(menuItem.getFullImage()).getLastPathSegment());

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap` object once you have used you need to call `recycle()` method which frees native resources.

[Bitmap#recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29)

> Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there are no other references. The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what have been said I would close the asset stream because depending on the platform you are running on the asset might not be closed automatically.
And even if it is you are keeping the file descriptor around for longer than you need it. It is a limited resource, so something else might went south as a result.